# CSS list menu rollover padding / margin

Tags: html, css, html-lists

im wondering if anyone could please help me with a css / html issue.

I have a complex background image. The menu div is positioned at the correct location to overlay the background where it is ment to position. The entire LI has a hover rollover image with a display type of block. The result is that when the mouse is over the list href the entire block rollover works..

The problem happens however when i attempt to add padding to create a buffer between the list item text and its border.. Things start to go funny... I'll add a screen shot.. Padding is required to move it from the border.

The second problem exists that i cant valign the text to the middle without applying a line height.. The solution works great until items wrap.. I need to be able to wrap menu item text..

The below example shows the state with the current CSS/HTML. The menu bar and rollover are in place as expected. Amend i cant place the image to to restrictions on posting as a new person here.. The example can however be found at 213.40.100.100 / example1.jpg

The below example shows the state when padding OR margin is added. The LI seems to completly shift, not moving the interal text..

213.40.100.100 / example2.jpg

```
 <div id="wrapper">      
  <div
  id="header">Header</div>      <div
  id="menu">
     <ul>
       <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
       <li><a>Recommends</a></li>
       <li><a>Deals</a></li>
       <li><a>Home</a></li>
     </ul>      </div>      <div id="content">Content</div>      
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>  
</div>




 @charset "utf-8"; /* CSS Document */



 * {  margin: 0;  padding: 0; }

 body {  
padding-top: 10px;
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center top;  height:100%; 
}

 div#wrapper {  
margin: auto;  
height: 100%;  
width: 978px;
  min-width: 978px;
 }

 div#header { 
 height: 196px;
 }

 div#menu { 
 height: 69px; 
 position:
 relative; 
}

 div#menu ul { 
 height: 69px;

  list-style-type: none; 
}

 div#menu ul li { 
 display: block;  

  height: 69px; 
 width: 140px; 
 float: right; 
 padding: 5px; 
}

 div#menu ul li a:hover {
  display:block;
  background:url(menu_red_bg.jpg) repeat-x;  height: 69px;  color:#FF0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size: large; 
}

 div#menu ul li a { 
 text-decoration: none; 
 color:#000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
 }

 div#content {  margin-top: 80px; }
```

Comment: Could you upload your image somewhere? The link does not work and I think the photo would really help to visualize what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are adding the padding to the wrong element. 
or you add a "margin" to the `<li>` or you add a padding to `div#menu`

I should do this:

A div#menu with the yellow gradient background, with the 5px padding and a margin: 80px 0 0 0;
Inside this div, the `<ul><li>...</li></ul>`
You don't need to add any padding or margin to the li, just be sure the height of each li is less than the `div#menu` heigh + padding.

Comment: Im using the li :hover css element to have a rollover for the entire height of the yellow bar.. 
Also because of the shadows aroudn the yellow bar i've had to include it on the background image of the actual page and not of the menu element..

Comment: You can use the shadows even if it's in the menu element. Just use a png image with transparency, there's a fix for IE6 which doesn't support transparency.

but even so, the idea is the same, use margin for the li element, just be sure the menu bar height is equal to li height + total padding.